How does buildroot select dts for compilation?
I have a Mango Pi Mq Quad, which uses the following overlay: https://github.com/readysloth/mangopi-buildroot-overlay. I have successfully built with the help of this overlay. However, now it is interesting to me -- how did the buildroot choose what dts to use? The board support "package" does not mention anything related.. Thanks for hints/full answers!
P. S. dts and dtb are different things. Basically my question is how does buildroot select dts to compile so that we have dtb as a result.

Depending on the Linux kernel, Buildroot could use one of two configuration methods for specification of the DT to be compiled. Refer to comments in the linux/Config.in Buildroot file.

@sawdust What are the two methods? Please give as much information as possible because this thread might come up in future when people would get interested in working with Buildroot and DTs.

In this setup, there are actually 3 device tree files to consider: the device tree used by ARM Trusted Firmware (TF-A), the device tree used by U-Boot, and the device tree used by the kernel.
Both TF-A and U-Boot normally have the device tree reference in the board configuration included in the source itself. For U-Boot, that's in the selected defconfig file, so in this case board/mangopi/configs/u-boot.config, which sets CONFIG_OF_LIST. As noted in the other answer, that is then overridden with the DEVICE_TREE=... make option but there's actually no reason to do that.
Note that Buildroot also allows to provide a U-Boot DTS from the board directory, by setting BR2_TARGET_UBOOT_CUSTOM_DTS_PATH.
For the kernel, you normally use either BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_INTREE_DTS_NAME or BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_DTS_PATH to specify the device tree. In this case, nothing of the sort is set, so I guess the kernel uses the device tree from U-Boot.

BR2_TARGET_UBOOT_CUSTOM_MAKEOPTS="DEVICE_TREE=sun50i-h616-orangepi-zero2"
So turns out the overlay is intended to work in the following way:

It first builds the dtb from Orange Pi dts.
It then copies the resulting dtb to some place and the loads Linux using this dtb.


What is/are "It"? The  "It" in #1 cannot possibly be the same  "It" in #2.

@sawdust I suppose that u-boot dts is used to build the linux image, correct?
